# Listening comprehension

Tags: listening

What is he saying [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=43e51vkffQE=70s)? (1:10)

In a sense in self-clarification

Or

innocence of self-clarification?

Comment: "... lies, in essence, in self-clarification".

Answer (score 1):

Neither, I'm afraid.

"The pleasure of talking about ourselves lies, in essence, in self-clarification"